# New view when button is pressed

Tags: ios, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have two buttons that randomly log text in a label. I want the label to display in a new view when the button is pressed. I'm not sure how to make this work. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is what I've got http://www.evernote.com/shard/s279/sh/82fe480a-84b5-4905-b6a5-d5012902e777/ebae497a39f779d079ae74a90d42657d

Comment: are you wanted to show different value in the lable for different button??

Comment: @Aminul no, both buttons do the same thing. I can't get the label to display text on button click unless its in the same view. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this tutorial to achieve your goal...
http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Only just change you have make in this method...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = @"Your desired text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard create a new view controller. Next control drag your button to that that view controller. Select Modal.

Comment: By the way when a answer is correct you can give a green check.

Comment: Actually I just realized this doesn't solve the problem. The button now loads a new view but no longer displays the text in the label.

Comment: You could use the prepareForSegueMethod to send you textFields text to another view controller.